# How do I get the result of a method called via delegate handler?

Tags: c#, delegates

The following code is just a homework task, therefore `delegate` there may look totally meaningless

So, I have a Hangman game class and it has a method that reads game data from a file. If that file is not found - a method from user code should be called:

```
 catch (FileNotFoundException)
 {
   exceptionOnLoad?.Invoke("File doesn't exist");
 }
```

So there I have a delegate and a handler method, that assigns a custom user method to it:

```
public delegate bool ExceptionErrorHandler(string message);
private ExceptionErrorHandler? exceptionOnLoad;
public void RegisterExceptionErrorHandler(ExceptionErrorHandler method)
{
   exceptionOnLoad = method;
}
```

So here's a method from user code that `exceptionOnLoad` is supposed to call:

```
static bool HandleOnErrorMessage(string message)
{      
   Console.WriteLine(message);
   return true;
}
```

It returns bool, because I'd like to use it as an indicator for stopping a Hangman game, but it is called via the following construction and there's nowhere to write that bool value to:

```
hangmanGame.RegisterExceptionErrorHandler(HandleOnErrorMessage);
```

Is there a way to store the bool-result of `HandleOnErrorMessage` in a variable? Or maybe there's a better way to use `delegate` and achieve desirable result in this situation?
I was thinking about this:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
   bool? load = exceptionOnLoad?.Invoke("File doesn't exist");
}
```

And then making a file loading method also output this bool, but this seems strange (maybe in vain).

Answer (score 1):

If it's for homework i would just .invoke() it like a simple method, as you described.

It's not a weird solution to be honest, the only weird thing here is the homework itself. I don't see any point on doing this other than learning about delegates, of course.

Here's a working example in a console application:

```
// We define the delegate
public delegate bool Handler(string message); 

// We assign a handler method with a lambda
public static Handler SomeHandler => HandlerMethod; 

public static bool HandlerMethod(string message)
{
    // Do what you need with the message and return a value
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // We call it and store the value in a variable!
    var variable = SomeHandler.Invoke("Some message"); 
}
```

Comment: Well let's assume so, but how to store the bool result of the method anyway?

Comment: @Morgen270 When you invoke the delegate, it should return the value you specified (boolean, in this case). I will post an example :)

Comment: So the strange idea wasn't that strange, thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
// you declared the delegate
public delegate bool ExceptionErrorHandler(string message);

// if you want to return the output of the delegate method, it needs to return 
// same type as such delegate
public bool RegisterExceptionErrorHandler(ExceptionErrorHandler method)
{  
    const string message = "Call from RegisterExceptionErrorHandler";
    if (method != null)  // can be null, yes
        return method(message);
    else
        return false;
}


// USAGE

private void DoSomething(SomeEnum val)
{

    bool retval;

    if (val == SomeEnum.Val1) // Based on enum value
        retval = RegisterExceptionErrorHandler(Method1); // you invoke one method or another
    else if (val == SomeEnum.Val2)
        retval = RegisterExceptionErrorHandler(Method2);
    else 
        retval = RegisterExceptionErrorHandler(Method3);

    if (retval)
        RunSomeCode();

}
```

Methods `Method1`, `Method2` and `Method3` must be declared with the signature of the `delegate` - `bool X(string)`